# To download image from directory with php

Tags: php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo '<img src="img/print.png" /><br>';
echo 'check';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I use this code for show the image in the we-browser
then I use this code to download the file with .doc format

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=nyoba.doc");
echo '<img src="img/print.png" /><br>';
echo 'check';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

but the image didn't just box with text image not found or has been remove,
what the solution for this problem?
Sorry I can speak English very well

Comment: Is it ok to show image from server?

Comment: yes, but if i want to download the image, the image will not found

Comment: I'm afraid that not possible, because the HTTP protocol was designed to send one file per one request.

Comment: so what must i do, to download the images in .doc file?

Comment: Either format a word document early with image inside of it already and then give a link to it or show external image.

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer Edvin

Comment: What you have tried there does not make any sense whatsoever. You can not send two different documents (a basic HTML document, and your word document) in response to the same request.